# ag-grid filter for particular column data using Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, ag-grid

I have a ag-grid in my ***Angular2 project*** with different columns (First Name, Last Name, Address, Phone Number). In that i have placed a filter. That filter works for entire table but i'm trying to do every column with individual filter input section (or) a filter input field according to the first name column.For more details view the picture==> [Chick here to view the Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isFLH.png)

Can any one help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing the filter via the filterFramework property of ColDef in the header component or in the main component by provided api.

```
        let field = this.params.column.getColId();
        //or field_name like (let field = 'first_name';)
        let agGridFilter = this.gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance(field);
        this.filterInstance = agGridFilter.getFrameworkComponentInstance();
```

. For more details you can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145764/angular2-ag-grid-ng2-how-to-embed-default-custom-filter-input-in-header-cell)